# How can I shorten this linq to sql query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am am making a calendar and to make it easier on myself I break up appointments that span over multiple weeks.

For instance Jan 1st to Jan 31st spans like 6 weeks(my calendar is always 42 cells - 6 by 7). So I would basically have 6 rows stored in my database.

However somethings I do require to me to put all these rows back together into one row. For instance if I want to export my calendar in Ical format.

I have a field in my database called bindingClassName all these rows get the same unquie id to that group of tasks so I am able to get all the weeks easily.

```
// get all of the task rows by binding class name.
            var found = plannerDb.Calendars.Where(u => u.UserId == userId && u.BindingClassName == bindingClassName)
                .GroupBy(u => u.BindingClassName);



            List<Calendar> allAppoingments = new List<Calendar>();

            // go through each of the results and add it to a list of calendars
            foreach (var group in found)
            {

                foreach (var row in group)
                {

                    Calendar appointment = new Calendar();
                    appointment.AppointmentId = row.AppointmentId;
                    appointment.AllDay = row.AllDay;
                    appointment.BindingClassName = row.BindingClassName;
                    appointment.Description = row.Description;
                    appointment.EndDate = row.EndDate;
                    appointment.StartDate = row.StartDate;
                    appointment.Title = row.Title;
                    appointment.Where = row.Where;
                    appointment.UserId = row.UserId;

                    allAppoingments.Add(appointment);
                }
            }
            // order 
           var test = allAppoingments.OrderBy(u => u.StartDate);

           var firstAppointment = test.First();
           var LastAppointment = test.Last();

           Calendar newAppointment = new Calendar();
           newAppointment.UserId = firstAppointment.UserId;
           newAppointment.Description = firstAppointment.Description;
           newAppointment.AllDay = firstAppointment.AllDay;
           newAppointment.StartDate = firstAppointment.StartDate;
           newAppointment.Title = firstAppointment.Title;
           newAppointment.Where = firstAppointment.Where;
           newAppointment.BindingClassName = firstAppointment.BindingClassName;
           newAppointment.EndDate = LastAppointment.EndDate;

            return newAppointment;
```

So basically that big blob finds all the appointments with the same binding name. Then I go through each one and make it into a Calendar object then finally once it is all made I get the first and last record to get the startDate and endDate.

So I am not good with linq but I am not sure if I can just add something after the groupBy to do what I want.

**Edit.**

I am trying group all my appointments together once I get all of them from the user.

So I have this so far

I tried something like this.

```
    var allApointments = calendar.GetAllAppointments(userId);
    var group = allApointments.GroupBy(u => u.BindingClassName).Select(u => new Calendar()).ToList
```

I was hoping that it would fill each group automatically but it does not. So I am not sure if don't need groupby again.

**Edit @ admin**

Hi thanks for explaining sorting and grouping. How you explained it though it seems either one would work.

Like the code you have for getting the first and last date works great and does what I wanted it to.

I think grouping might have worked because in the end though I am looking just to have one row that has the startdate of the first record and the end date of the last record all the other information would be the same.

So I don't know if it would harder to write that instead or what but like I said your query does what I want.

However that query is used on a single basis. Like I use that query only when a user clicks to view that appointment on my calendar. By clicking on the appointment I get all the information about that appointment and thats where I need to look at if that task spans over multiple days and figure out when the appointment started and when it is going to end.

Now I need another query and I think it would be better if I could actually group them as how I understand it from your explanation it will make one row. the reason I think this is because I want to export all the records in the table from that user.

So if I order them into one continues block by binding name I still going to need some loops that goes through all the records and gets the first and start date. So if I could just group it in one go and the final result would be just one record for each group of binding names and it would have the first start date and the last end date from the first and last record would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you grouping the appointments if you aren't actually using the group? It looks like you're just using them individually. In any case, you're already filtering the rows on a single value for `BindingClassName` in the `Where` clause, so you would only end up with 1 (or 0) group(s) anyway.

You can rewrite that series of `foreach` loops into a `Select` and `ToList()` like this:

```
var allAppointments = 
    plannerDb.Calendars.Where(
    row => row.UserId == userId && 
           row.BindingClassName == bindingClassName).OrderBy(
    row => row.StartDate).Select(
    row => new Calendar()
    {
        AppointmentId = row.AppointmentId,
        AllDay = row.AllDay,
        BindingClassName = row.BindingClassName,
        Description = row.Description,
        EndDate = row.EndDate,
        StartDate = row.StartDate,
        Title = row.Title,
        Where = row.Where,
        UserId = row.UserId
    }).ToList();
```

This will give you back the full list in the order you wanted. However, I'm curious why you're retrieving the whole list when it *looks* like you're only interested in the first and last appointment. You could instead do this:

```
var baseQuery = 
        plannerDb.Calendars.Where(
        row => row.UserId == userId && 
               row.BindingClassName == bindingClassName);

var first = baseQuery.OrderBy(row => row.StartDate).First();
var last = baseQuery.OrderByDescending(row => row.StartDate).Select(
           row => row.EndDate).First();

return new Calendar()
{
    AppointmentId = first.AppointmentId,
    AllDay = first.AllDay,
    BindingClassName = first.BindingClassName,
    Description = first.Description,
    EndDate = last,
    StartDate = first.StartDate,
    Title = first.Title,
    Where = first.Where,
    UserId = first.UserId
});
```

This should produce outputs that are the same as what you have now. I would question, however, if this is exactly what you want. Say you have two appointments:

- Appointment 1 starts January 5 and ends on January 10
- Appointment 2 starts January 6 and ends on January 7

Using this (and your) logic, you would get the end date as January 7, since Appointment 2 has the larger start date, but Appointment 1 actually ends later. I would recommend changing the second query to this:

```
var last = baseQuery.OrderByDescending(row => row.EndDate).Select(
           row => row.EndDate).First();
```

This will give you the largest *end date*, which I think is what you're actually after.

**EDIT**

I think you're making the (*very common*) mistake of confusing grouping with sorting. When you say you want to "group the appointments by the binding name", it sounds like you want a full, complete list of appointments, and you want those appointments arranged in such a way as all appointments with a particular binding name form a contiguous block. If that's the case, you want to order the list by the binding name, not group them. Grouping takes the whole list and produces one row per grouping clause and allows you to perform aggregation functions on the remaining columns. For example, let's say I group the appointments on the binding name. This means that my result set will contain *one row per binding name*, and I can then do things like find the maximum start or end date or something like that; more formally, you can specify aggregation operations, which are operations that take a set of data (i.e. a list of start dates) and return a single piece of data (i.e. the maximum start date).

Unless I'm misunderstanding, it sounds like you still want to retrieve all of the individual assignments, you just want them arranged by binding name. If this is the case, just `OrderBy(row => row.BindingName)` and it will do the trick. In addition, you may want to avoid using the word "group", as people will think you mean the sort of grouping that I described above.

Comment: I believe that the OP uses the last appointment to figure out the end date of the event: newAppointment.EndDate = LastAppointment.EndDate.

Comment: @anton: Yeah, I realized that. I've made the appropriate edits.

Comment: Well as I stated in my post I am not good with linq so I sort of tried to think of it in terms of an sql statement(what I am not good at either). Then tried to combine those together to try to make some statement that would work. Yes you are correct I am only looking for the first and last date.  I don't think what you stated is actually a problem. Like lets take your first example Appointment 1. It goes from January 5th to 10th. I have other code that would break this up into 2 records in my db. First one would be Jan 5th to 9th and the other would be Jan 10th to Jan 10th. I would........

Comment: then take the id from the first record(Jan 5th to 9th) take its primary key id field(lets say it is 1) and use that as the binding class name. So in my db both records would have bindName = "1". So then your second appointment would be a new record and it would be Jan 6th to Jan 7th and would have a bindName = "2". So it would not be taken since it has a different binding name. Now when they export their calendar it will look for the same binding names and get the start and end date and if all goes right it should be Jan 5 to 10th. Like I said it was just easier for me to break it up but other

Comment: calendars probably don't break up the records if it spans multiple weeks(they probably do it on the fly). However I just don't have the time to get that working maybe in future versions.

Comment: @chobo: The same point still stands if you have one appointment that starts on Monday and lasts until Thursday, then another starts on Tuesday and lasts until Wednesday. Just using the logic above, the Tuesday appointment would be chosen, even though the Monday appointment ends later. If you don't feel it's a problem, then feel free to leave it as-is. I just thought I'd point it out.

Comment: Well I am not sure if this is a problem or not. How I see it is not. I just tired with your sample data. I made an appointment called Test1 and had it span from Jan 5th to 10th. I then made another appointment called Test2 what span from Jan 6th to Jan 7th. When I click on Test1 on my calendar it pops up a menu that shows the start date and end date. This shows Jan 5th to Jan 10th as expected. When I click on Test2 it shows Jan 6th to Jan 7th. I will keep a look out on this and if I see something like your describing it will be the first thing I check.

Comment: On a side note I actually need to do actually to statements. Like I want to get all the users appointments. Then I want to group them together by the binding name. So same sort of thing but instead I want it all to be in a collection of Calendars. So if I had Say 3 binding ones with "1" and 2 binding ones with "2" I would end up with all the 1' group together as a calendar event and all the 2's grouped together as a calendar event. Then these 2 calendar events stored in a List<Calendar> events.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a side point not concerning the linq, have you looked at [AutoMapper](http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper)? I am currently using this for populating data objects from linq and I've found it really useful for getting rid of the large sections of code where you just map to dtos. It wouldn't make the query parts of your code any shorter but would reduce:

```
return new Calendar()
{
    AppointmentId = first.AppointmentId,
    AllDay = first.AllDay,
    BindingClassName = first.BindingClassName,
    Description = first.Description,
    EndDate = last,
    StartDate = first.StartDate,
    Title = first.Title,
    Where = first.Where,
    UserId = first.UserId
});
```

to:

```
return Mapper.Map(first,new Calendar{EndDate = last});
```